# How to remove time part of list of datetime strings?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of 1000 different dates and time strings like below in python.

```
dates[:3] == 
  ['2019-11-29 12:50:54',
    '2019-11-29 12:46:53',
    '2019-11-29 12:46:10']
```

I would like to get these strings so that it only shows the date part and not the time for all 1000 in the list like example below.

```
date_only(dates[:3]) == ['2019-11-29', '2019-11-29', '2019-11-29']
```

Comment: `[d[:10] for d in dates]`?

Comment: Thanks it works :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply `split()` the array

```
dates =['2019-11-29 12:50:54', '2019-11-29 12:46:53','2019-11-29 12:46:10']

for i in range(len(dates)):
    date = [dates[i].split()[0]]
    print(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the list is already string object, you can use `split()` and get the first element which is date only:

```
dates =  ['2019-11-29 12:50:54', '2019-11-29 12:46:53', '2019-11-29 12:46:10']
dateonly = [elt.split()[0] for elt in dates]
print(dateonly)
```